# Node.js and socket.io with SSL - Segmentation fault in libcrypto

Tags: node.js, ssl, socket.io, segmentation-fault, libcrypto

My server runs CentOS 7 with Node.js and NPM installed by Yum.

Dependencies installed and compiled by NPM: socket.io, express

- Node.js 6.12.3
- Socket.io 2.0.4
- Express 4.16.2

SSL cert generated by Let's Encrypt.

I'm receiving an error in libcrypto:

```
Feb  1 16:34:17 orfeu kernel: node[3330]: segfault at 1 ip 00007fb2cca17acc sp 00007ffe82ca8020 error 4 in libcrypto.so.1.0.2k[7fb2cc8f3000+234000]
```

My script:

```
const fs=require('fs');
const https=require('https');
const express=require('express');
const app=express();

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/orfeu.domain.com.br/privkey.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/orfeu.domain.com.br/fullchain.pem')
};

const server=https.createServer(options,app);
const socket=require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(444);

socket.on('connection',function(client) {
   client.on('disconnect',onDisconnect);
   function onDisconnect() { client.removeListener('disconnect',onDisconnect); }
});
```

It runs, but when the first client connects, I get a "Segmentation fault" error.

Any ideas how to fix this? Thank you.